# Generate two sequences that have a pre-specified rank correlation

Tags: correlation, kendall-tau

I have two samples $ X_1,\cdots,X_n $ and $ Y_1, \cdots, Y_n $, and would like to re-order them so that they have a pre-specified value of rank correlation such as Kendall's tau.

I do know that there are many ways to generate two samples that have a specific Pearson's correlation coefficient, but don't know whether there is a way to do this about Kendall's tau.

Comment: I answered a generalization of this question at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3961, but I suspect for your special case their *might* exist better solutions.